# Linear factor analysis to find stationary factors?

Tags: time-series, factor-analysis

I have a multivariate time series. My model assumption is that it was generated from underlying factors, some of which are stationary, using a linear mixing.

How can I access the stationary factors? I have tried independent component analysis (ICA), but the independence assumption is too strong.

Comment: Are you aware of Dynamic Factor Analysis? See this publication, [Molenaar, De Gooijer & Schmitz (1992)](http://www1.fee.uva.nl/pp/bin/refereedjournalpublication1976fulltext.pdf) for an example.

Comment: Can DFA find the _most_ stationary set of factors? This is what I'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure, a closer read of the paper I linked to would probably not prove fruitful for this, but it doesn't seem so far fetched an extension has been made to allow more reasonable identification of non-stationary vs stationary factors (non-stationary in the linked paper just means a linear trend in the latent series!). Another potential approach may be to "prune" the non-stationary series from the panel and then only estimate the DFM on the known stationary series (although that seems slightly un-satisfactory). Good luck, I'm not sure I can give any more advice.